# ANTLR cannot find counter symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors, antlr, antlr3, symbols

I've been searching everywhere for an answer to this problem but so far I have found none. I'm working on an ANTLR project that should basically implement a Haskell like grammar.

```
listDecl:
LIST {int count=0; ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();} (WS)+ ID '=' '[' a1=atom {count++; list.add($a1.value);} (',' a2=atom {count++; list.add($a2.value);} )* ']' {listMemory.put($ID.text, list);}
;
```

The above part of the code along with a few others that follow the same basic format are giving me the following errors:

```
TParser.java:510: error: cannot find symbol
          count++; list.add(a1);
          ^
symbol:   variable count
location: class TParser
TParser.java:510: error: cannot find symbol
          count++; list.add(a1);
                   ^
symbol:   variable list
location: class TParser
TParser.java:534: error: cannot find symbol
                  count++; list.add(a2);
                  ^
symbol:   variable count
location: class TParser
TParser.java:534: error: cannot find symbol
                  count++; list.add(a2);
                           ^
symbol:   variable list
location: class TParser
TParser.java:547: error: cannot find symbol
          listMemory.put((ID6!=null?ID6.getText():null), list);
                                                         ^
```

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but after extensive research I've honestly given up hope
Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to mention that this rule is for declaring and storing lists of integers... I dunno if it makes any difference but i thought i'd mention it anw...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `count` and `list` local variables to be visible throughout the rule, you need to declare them in an `@init` block.

```
listDecl
@init {
  int count = 0;
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
  : LIST WS+ ID '=' '[' a1=atom {count++; list.add($a1.value);}
    ( ',' a2=atom {count++; list.add($a2.value);}
    )*
    ']' {listMemory.put($ID.text, list);}
  ;
```